# Have space station modules already been replaced?

Tags: iss, space-station

After reading [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/237/9072), I understand that it is simpler to replace a space station than to repair it in order to continue its activity. All modules in a space station may not have the same lifespan (I may be mistaken, but a space station take several years to build, and  is expected to be in service for about 10 years).

Moreover, it is possible to add modules to a space station. It may be possible to jettison modules as well. Given this, I imagine an old obsolete module may be dropped and then a new one may take its place in order to maintain its mission and avoid building a new space station from scratch. But I cannot find any historical records of such an operation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It hasn't happened yet, but ISS docking module [Pirs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirs_(ISS_module)) is scheduled to be deorbited and replaced by laboratory module [Nauka](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauka_(ISS_module)).

Edit: It happened in July 2021 (see links)

Answer (score 17):

The only module(s) that kinda sorta fits this are/were the MPLMs - the Multi Purpose Logistics Modules.

[image]

These modules were carried up by the Shuttle full of cargo, berthed to the ISS using robotics, emptied out, and then filled up with trash for the return trip.  They were then detached robotically and restowed in the Shuttle bay.

The MPLMs were built by the Italian Space Agency and were named *Leonardo*, *Donatello*, and *Raffaello*.  For reasons that escape me, *Donatello* was never used, but the other two flew 12 round trip missions to the ISS.

Near the end of the Shuttle program, mission STS-133 (Feb 2011) took *Leonardo* up and it was attached permanently to the ISS becoming the Permanent Multipurpose Module.

Continuing its odyssey, in 2015 *Leonardo*/PMM was moved from its original "permanent" location on Node 1 Nadir, to Node 3 Forward.  [This was done to allow more visiting vehicles to be present at the ISS simultaneously.](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2015/05/iss-program-station-reconfiguration-future-crew-vehicles/)

Here's a super sped up video of that move:

So one could say that *Leonardo* was attached and removed multiple times, (sometimes replaced by *Raffaello*) and finally attached and left as an ISS module.  Not sure if that meets your criteria though.

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Purpose_Logistics_Module)

Comment: Check out the official logo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Purpose_Logistics_Module#/media/File:Multi-Purpose_Logistics_Module_Logo.png

Answer (score 4):

The Russian plan for the station, after it is retired by the International partners is to take the new Nauka module (Referenced by Quentin) and its attached docking module (OM) and make those the base of their new station, and grow it from there.

So in that case it is add new modules, and throw away old ones, sort of what the question asks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this has never happened. There's no particular reason it couldn't be done though.

Comment: Well for some modules, there are lots of reasons.  :)  Inline modules, connected at both ends would be really hard to replace without a shuttle.  Maybe the CanadaArm2 could hold one half of the station, but you need a second hand.  Also, as Quentin answered, Pirs is about to be replaced by Nauka.

Comment: Not a problem actually. Dock a resupply vehicle to the smaller piece you're trying to keep and unberth that. Grab the module you're ditching with Canadarm 2 and either chuck it so it can deorbit or stick it somewhere else to get rid of later. Have the resupply vehicle maneuver the piece you're trying to keep close enough, and the Candarm does the rest.

Plus the European Robotic Arm is supposed to come soon.

Comment: Another option would be for the arm to move the piece of the station which you want to keep to a temporary berthing location.

Comment: There are a lot of external cabling/plumbing connections that are hooked up via EVA that would have to be unhooked via EVA.  The ISS is not made of Legos.

Comment: I never said there wasn't other work that would need to be done. I was addressing the comment about needing the space shuttle.

Since the ISS is equipped for EVA, needing to perform an EVA is not a valid reason that the module can't be removed.

Comment: Downvotes on this post are unwarranted.  It answered precisely the question asked, and it did so correctly.